# Selenium web driver moveToElement (Actions) throwing error with marionette driver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber-java, firefox-marionette

Getting following error in selenium tests

```
POST /session/ee1b9201-dadc-7446-b753-0a418a230d30/moveto did not match a known command
```

What i've done is

```
Actions resetView = new Actions(driver);
resetView.moveToElement(el).perform();
```

Environment:

Firefox v47.0

Webdriver 3.0.0-beta2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is entirely expected. No releases of GeckoDriver (Marionette) support the `Actions` class. It is one of the top priorities of Mozilla's team developing Marionette.

Comment: so 2 months passed and still no support. But I want to believe that it is one of top priorities as you mentioned here

Comment: Here we are at Nov 1st, still doesn't work as of geckodriver 0.11.1 ;

IMHO being unable to run a comprehensive test suite should be a release blocker for any of the big web browsers. With the deprecation of WebDriver support, it's essentially impossible to test your web app on current versions of Firefox, which leads to pressure to keep old versions in opposition to trying to keep up to date for security.

Comment: I'll just take a minute to point out that the Selenium project had no control over the deprecation of the open-source Firefox driver. It was rendered inoperable by Firefox architecture changes. The use of Marionette is the way forward, and it **is** open-source (most Mozilla code is), so if you're not seeing the progress you'd like to on Marionette, it's possible to contribute toward making it happen. But complaining about Mozilla's slow movement on implementation here isn't likely to get the result you want.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [issue that Selenium tracks](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2285), that [is blocked by the Marionette issue](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/159).

Since the issue it's over 3 weeks old, and looking at their [commit log](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/commits/master), I wouldn't hold my breath for a patch anytime soon.

If you can use Firefox 47.0.1, [because in Firefox 47.0 they had another bug](http://www.germaniumhq.com/2016/07/03/2016-07-03-What-Do-We-Learn-from-the-Broken-Firefox-WebDriver-Support/), you can use the old WebDriver API that works (not Marionette). From 48 it stopped working, because you're supposed to use Marionette. Yes, that Marionette that is not finished.

If you *must* test on Firefox, I recommend you should stick to Firefox 47.0.1, Selenium 2.latest, eventually throw them in a docker image, and run like that.

That's what I do at least for [Germanium](http://www.germaniumhq.com/), until it will hopefully eventually work also for Marionette.

Comment: This should be the Mozilla issue tracking other issues that revolve around "actions": https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292178. It needs to be resolved to yield support of `mouseMoveTo` instructions. Some comments in the referenced issues set the milestone "Firefox 55" (though some previous milestones have been reverted at least two times).