# Getting Error while running moveToElement() method in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm pretty new to selenium and when i'm running code below for Selenium WebDriver in Eclipse (Java), i'm getting this exception:

> **"Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: mouseMoveTo"**

Here is the code:

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
    WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=userName]"));

    Actions myAction = new Actions(driver);
    myAction.moveToElement(myElement)
        .click()
        .keyDown(myElement, keys.SHIFT)
        .sendKeys(myElement, "test")
        .keysUp(myElement, keys.SHIFT)
        .(myElement)
        .contextClick()
        .build()
        .perform();
```

What causes this error?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a known issue with the new Version of the FirefoxDriver namely the GeckoDriver, which doesn´t support the Action class see:

[Selenium web driver moveToElement (Actions) throwing error with marionette driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104732/selenium-web-driver-movetoelement-actions-throwing-error-with-marionette-drive)

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3348

Without more info I´d assume this is also your problem. If you need to test with FF then use an older version or Chrome with the ChromeDriver

Comment: Thanks Dude.. I used ChromeDriver() and It Works!!

Answer (score 3):

Try this below xpath:

**Explanation:** Your `input` tag, parent tag is `table` so start `xpath` with `table` tag and then move ahead with using `following` keyword to `input` tag.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/../following::input[@name='userName']")).sendKeys("USERNAME");
```

Comment: Hi, My code is working till actions class initialization. But thanx for reply

Comment: As Enrique pointed out i think problem must be in GreckoDriver ..

Comment: @Rishabh Can you explain why you are going with `Action class` here for handling this `username` text box?

Comment: This is not the right way for practicing, your approach is totally wrong over here. Action class is used for drag and drop the element and hovering effect of the element to the use.

Comment: ok.. Thanks for pointing out. Will keep in mind..

Comment: hello, though you told me to xpath. ""driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/../following::input[@name='userName']")).sendKeys("USERNAME");"" But my old xpath was also working. The problem was not in Xpath but in Grecko Driver. iused ChromeDriver and it worked so i accepted @enrique medina's answer

Comment: Xpath was working but real problem was in grecko driver.

Comment: @Rishabh I have seen that your `cssSelector` was wrong in your code. So the Issue is not related with action class, Issue is with your wrong css. It should be like that `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='userName']"));`

Comment: So, I guess my this answer should get accepted, because i have provided valid `xpath` as well as valid `cssSelector`.

Comment: Have you notice your mistake in cssSelector? Your code = `input[name=userName]` and correct code = `input[name='userName']`

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:** Your `cssSelector` is incorrect, Use single quote for attribute value.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='userName']"));
```