# Getting org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: mouseMoveTo

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I am using selenium 3.5.3 and standalone selenium box.
I am trying to hover an element with following code:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = null;
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability("browserName", "firefox");
dc.setCapability("version", "55");
dc.setCapability("auth",GlobalProperties.seleniumboxAuthKey());
try {
     driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new 
URL("http://myseleniumboxurl.com/wd/hub"), dc);
}
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
driver.get("https://github.com/SeleniumHQ");
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/pricing')]"));
action.moveToElement(elem).perform();
```

I am getting following exception:
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: mouseMoveTo

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpCommandCodec.encode(AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java:220)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpCommandCodec.encode(AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java:118)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteExecuteMethod.execute(RemoteExecuteMethod.java:35)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteMouse.mouseMove(RemoteMouse.java:89)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.internal.EventFiringMouse.mouseMove(EventFiringMouse.java:58)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.interactions.MouseMoveToLocation.call(MouseMoveToLocation.java:59)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.interactions.MouseMoveToLocation.call(MouseMoveToLocation.java:32)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any possible workaround or solution please?

Comment: At which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: Update firefox driver..Then check it and let me know

Comment: @PaulKertscher Exception is thrown at action.moveToElement(elem).perform();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium web driver moveToElement (Actions) throwing error with marionette driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104732/selenium-web-driver-movetoelement-actions-throwing-error-with-marionette-drive)

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium 3.5.0 mouse move not working properly. So you can use java script libraries and use a java script command to mouse move on element

Comment: I tried using 
    String moveTo = "var fireEvent = arguments[0];" + "var evObj = 
    document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" + "evObj.initEvent( 
'mouseover', true, true );" + "fireEvent.dispatchEvent(evObj);";
    driver.executeScript(moveTo, element);

This also doesn't work.

Can you please suggest?

Comment: No you can update the browser version and the selenium version. Now its working fine.